# Javascript: cannot enter zeros after a decimal point

Tags: javascript, reactjs, numbers

Basically I am working on a calculator app and noticed that there's is the following bug in my program:
whenever I try to enter any zero after a decimal in my float number it doesn't allow me to do so.

I assume that the problem in my code is somewhere in the following function, but not sure what is exactly wrong.

```
function handleChange() {
  const { value } = event.target

  // if (isCalculated) {
  //  handleDelete()
  //}

  if (value === "." && !displayNum.toString().includes(".")) {
    setDisplayNum(prevValue => prevValue.toString().concat("."))
  } else if (regex.test(displayNum)) {
    setDisplayNum(value)
  } else {
    setDisplayNum(prevValue => parseFloat(prevValue.toString().concat(value)))
  }
}
```

Value passed can be numbers from 0-9 and "." and regex is `let regex = /\+|-|\*|\//`.

Here's also my [pen](https://codepen.io/konstantinkrumin/pen/gOPPaJB?editors=0011).

P.S. setDisplayNum() is just setting the React state hook value to track down the changes.

Comment: You'll need to change your approach a bit.  The code currently doesn't handle math operations correctly

Comment: @user120242 seems that with this modification mentioned below, my code is working for all instances I tested, at least visually. Could you show me please where it is working incorrectly?

Comment: I'm looking at the test cases you have in there.  Does it not need to pass them?  It appears to depend on it being a number or string to pass part of the tests, but this causes subsequent tests to fail, because the + operator (concatenation) behaves differently after the math operations?  Depending on parseFloat and number vs string behavior with + operator appears to be causing a catch 22 where one or the other test will fail

Comment: @user120242 oh yes true, I have an issue with those test cases for while since when I look inside them it shows as like I'm passing 0 as a final results rather than a correct value, but visually my code is giving a correct answer. I'm using eval() function to get a final output. Wouldn't it convert my final result to an expected integer or float for the test cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`parseFloat()` strips the trailing zeros after a decimal point, you can use `toFixed()` for which you need to calculate the numbers after the decimal point.

```js
function handleChange() {
  const {
    value
  } = event.target

  if (isCalculated) {
    handleDelete()
  }

  if (value === "." && !displayNum.toString().includes(".")) {
    setDisplayNum(prevValue => prevValue.toString().concat("."))
  } else if (regex.test(displayNum)) {
    setDisplayNum(value)
  } else {
    setDisplayNum(prevValue => {
      const prevValStr = prevValue.toString();
      let numbersAfterDecimal = 0;
      if (prevValStr.includes('.')) {
        numbersAfterDecimal = prevValStr.split('.')[1].length;
        // for current value
        numbersAfterDecimal++;
      }
      return parseFloat(prevValStr.concat(value)).toFixed(numbersAfterDecimal);

    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's just the way `parseFloat()` works:

```
console.log(parseFloat('1.0'));
> 1
```

Comment: It happens though in instance when 0 is entered not immediately after the '.'. For example, I would not be able to enter 9.39002

Comment: That's because handleChange() is called after every change.  When the number is 9.39 and you try to enter a zero, it treats it as a trailing zero and removes it.